# ViewPage on MVC doesnt show the class properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have created a simple class which contains three properties

```
ID
Name
Amount
```

i have passed the namespace of model to controller class, as

```
public class _1Controller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /1/
        Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            return View();
        }

        public ViewResult DisplayCustomer()
        {
            Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
            objCustomer.ID = 12;
            objCustomer.Name = "1001";
            objCustomer.Amount = 90.34;

            return View("DisplayCustomer", objCustomer);
        }

    }
```

when i have bind the controller class to a view,as

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.Customer

@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DisplayCustomer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       The customer id is <%= Model.Id %> <br /> 
       the customer Name is <%= M
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i am trying to call class properties, it doesn't show.
i have clicked the strongly typed `checkbox` while binding the view to a controller.Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I am new to MVC, an explanation would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC3 has a number of razor Html helper methods to accomplish this.

Instead of

```
<%= Model.Id %>
```

try this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
```

[Here is a list of these helper on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper_methods%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Just another thing to add, if you aren't already using the tutorials on the [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site then give them a try, they're a great starting point.